# SQLiteDatabase table per .db file

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
// The database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "waitlist.db";

// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Hey guys, I was following a tutorial containing this code snippet. As it was a small tutorial the DATABASE_NAME and the Version where inside the WaitlistDBHelper Class. The waitlist table is the only table of the database. I thought including the database name here was just out of ease and tried to reuse the same database_name and version for 3 different tables and corresponding DBHelper classes. It seems like that there can only be one table inside one .db file.

Is this correct?

I receive “table not found exceptions” for two out of three tables and it seems like the table I create first will be created and the other two won't. I was using the database name intuitively as I thought it's actually a database where you can save more tables in the same .db file.

I would be more than happy for support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `It seems like that there can only be one table inside one .db file.

Is this correct?` **NO**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` manages database files, not tables. If you want to have more than one table in your database file, put them in the same `SQLiteOpenHelper` class that creates all the tables in its `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Can you tell me what's better practice: to use one DBhelper for all tables or separate tables into different files?

Comment: Only if the tables are totally disconnected then you might be better off keeping them separate. Usually data in different tables are related. It's a relational database after all.